# Change the position of a Stylesheet in a Joomla site

Tags: css, templates, stylesheet

I have a joomla site. And I have a component installed which has it's own css file positioned in the actual component files, I would like to position this css file to another folder (not in component files), so I copied the css file to where I need to, and now I'm looking where in the code is written the PATH to the css file... and I found the code :

```
$this->addCSS('layout');
```

the file is called "layout.css".

How can I change this code to a path something like "/template/bluedilema/css/layout.css"

Somebody PLEASE help if you can.

Thanks

Comment: This is a joomla issue, you should add the "joomla" tag

Comment: Hi, can you please explain more what do you mean by "joomla" tag ? thank you

Comment: This isn't exactly a CSS issue, but an issue with how Joomla loads files. You're more likely to find help adding the tag 'joomla' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/joomla

Comment: nope, I did already the same to other Joomla css files and there the "link" of css files is different, it's like "<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/style.css" type="text/css" />", but here as you see it's different...

Comment: I DID it !!!!!!!!!!!

I made it like 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/layout.css" type="text/css" />

I wrote this OUT the <?php ?> tags and it works )))

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
$this->addCSS('./../template/bluedilema/css/layout.css');
```

Please note you have to adjust the path.

Hope this link will help you!
http://www.howtojoomla.net/how-tos/development/how-to-add-cssjavascript-to-your-joomla-extension

Comment: Hi. I copied the css file in root path just to test and inserted like : $this->addCSS('/layout.css');  , but it doesn't recognize the path..

Comment: I DID it !!!!!!!!!!!

I made it like 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/layout.css" type="text/css" />

I wrote this OUT the <?php ?> tags and it works )))